# Mutual Certificate Authentication with Azure APIM

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-app-service-envrmnt

We have multiple device which access microservice via Azure APIM. Each device has wrapper, for example Mobile wrapper which access microservice. Now i want to do mutual certificate authentication in order to restrict mobile wrapper accessing microservice directly via APIM. Hence we decided to install client certificate at mobile wrapper which is hosted on Azure Appservice and server certificate at Azure APIM to do authentication before connecting to microservices. Similarly we have multiple client certificate for individual device wrapper like whatsapp bot, FB etc which will be interacting with APIM. My question is if this approach is feasible from architecture perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Sure that would work, just make sure that you actually test for a client certificate in APIM policy (context.Request.ClientCertificates) and validate them somehow. You could compare thumbprint to a predefined hardcoded value, or call .Validate on a certificate if all of them are issued by limited number of CA, and CA cert is uploaded into APIM.

Comment: Thanks Vitaliy, We have had same approach as you mentioned, but doesn't seems to be working. Throwing 403. With single client certificate i am able to authenticate, but with multiple client certificate not able to. Also we have configured multiple thumbprints.

Comment: Could you post your policy code? Make sure to hide all secrets if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

I addressed a similar issue by uploading the certificates to the Azure APIM configuration and establishing a condition in the API policy to confirm the existence of the certificate thumbprint. It worked perfectly. You can upload the certificates in Azure Key Vault and reference it in APIM configs as well.

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null || !context.Deployment.Certificates.Any(c => c.Value.Thumbprint == context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint))">
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="403" reason="Invalid client certificate" />
                </return-response>
            </when>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```